# Error while creating backup database copy of Exchange 2013 on DAG.

Tags: exchange, dag

Created a DAG for Exchange 2013 between two mailbox servers. Server 1 is main , Server 2 is connected via Cisco VPN client to Server 1 network. Trying to start the seeding process to create a backup copy of the mailbox to Server 2.

Get the following error:

The seeding operation failed. Error: An error occurred while performing the seed operation. Error: An error occurred
while communicating with server 'Server 1'. Error: Cannot determine the frame size or a corrupted frame was
received. [Database: Mailbox Database 2143525880, Server: Server2.domain.local]

tried modifying the network adapter parameters. Jumbo frame, RX limit, TCP offload etc.

but nothing worked

Server 1 is Windows VM running on VirtualBox behind a Cisco ASA firewall
Server 2 is windows VM running on VMWare connected to Cisco ASA via Cisco VPN client.

Server 1 and Server 2 can ping each other, access each others resources. No firewall rules blocking traffic between VPN network and internal LAN.

Any ideas on where to look would be really appreciated

Comment: `1.` VirtualBox isn't a proper virtualization platform for production workloads. `2.` VMware is a company, what VMware product is server 2 running on?

Comment: Yes you're right. I will be moving Server 1 to a Hyper-V environment soon. Server 2 is on a ESXi platform. I have solved the issue , by ensuring the exchange versions are exactly the same (I had to install a service pack on server 2, to get the versions matching). Also, i had to manually copy the exchange database from server 1 to server 2, while keeping the database offline. and then start the database, and restart the seeding process. After this, the database copy started showing as healthy. maybe the connection between the two servers was too weak to copy the database while running.

Comment: This link was very helpful http://www.petri.com/seed-exchange-2010-dag-database.htm